# What is the meaning of "pump"

Tags: meaning

I'm reading (Cambridge Collocation in use) and find this sentence and I don't fully understand it.

> There was good news for motorists today as pump prices were lowered by the major oil companies.

So *pump* here motor or what?

Comment: *pump prices* is idiomatic shorthand for *prices charged for what comes out of the pumps at filling stations* (i.e. - the price of petrol/diesel at garage forecourts, as opposed to the price of fuel oil on the international spot market).

Comment: These are "pumps". https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1521&bih=935&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=uhhuWvS2KNK0_AbqjoGIAw&q=gas+station+pump+google+images&oq=gas+station+pump+google+images&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2517.3667.0.4065.5.5.0.0.0.0.113.366.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.M1Pj3DZJZ3Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of prices to motorists and oil companies, "pump prices" means the prices of gasoline or petrol or similar liquid fuel sold in a retail station serving automobiles. The stations typically have multiple free-standing machines that pump the fuel from an underground tank into a hose having a nozzle that inserts into a vehicle's fuel tank fill pipe. Such machines are often called "pumps," and typically have the price of the product per unit volume (gallon, liter) on them in a display window.

So "pump prices" means the prices of automobile fuel per unit volume.